# Set the location of a PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, layout, android-preferences

I am using PreferenceFragment and a PreferenceScreen to show several settings. This is pretty OK in portrait mode. My app is used with VR goggles. In this landscape mode, the settings cannot be read because they are too far at the edge of the screen. I'd like to show the PrefernceScreen in a RelativeLayout with fixed width and android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal". How could I achiev this?

My code:

```
   public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content , new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            ...
```

My PreferenceScreen layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:entries="@array/connections"
        android:entryValues="@array/connectionvalues"
        android:key="Connection"
        android:title="PC connection" />
        ...
```